# Count number of non-NaN entries in each column of Spark dataframe in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a very large dataset that is loaded in Hive (about 1.9 million rows and 1450 columns). I need to determine the "coverage" of each of the columns, meaning, the fraction of rows that have non-NaN values for each column.

Here is my code:

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
import string as string

sc = SparkContext(appName="compute_coverages") ## Create the context
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.sql("select * from data_table")
nrows_tot = df.count()

covgs = sc.parallelize(df.columns)
          .map(lambda x: str(x))
          .map(lambda x: (x, float(df.select(x).dropna().count()) / float(nrows_tot) * 100.))
```

Trying this out in PySpark shell, if I then do `covgs.take(10)`, it returns a rather large error stack. It says that there's a problem in save in the file `/usr/lib64/python2.6/pickle.py`. This is the final part of the error:

> ```
> py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o37.__getnewargs__. Trace:
> py4j.Py4JException: Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist
>         at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:333)
>         at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:342)
>         at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:252)
>         at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
>         at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
>         at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> ```

Is there a better way to accomplish this? I can't use pandas, though, as it's not currently available on the cluster I work on and I don't have access rights to install it.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Let's start with a dummy data:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

row = Row("v", "x", "y", "z")
df = sc.parallelize([
    row(0.0, 1, 2, 3.0), row(None, 3, 4, 5.0),
    row(None, None, 6, 7.0), row(float("Nan"), 8, 9, float("NaN"))
]).toDF()

## +----+----+---+---+
## |   v|   x|  y|  z|
## +----+----+---+---+
## | 0.0|   1|  2|3.0|
## |null|   3|  4|5.0|
## |null|null|  6|7.0|
## | NaN|   8|  9|NaN|
## +----+----+---+---+
```

All you need is a simple aggregation:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, count, isnan, lit, sum

def count_not_null(c, nan_as_null=False):
    """Use conversion between boolean and integer
    - False -> 0
    - True ->  1
    """
    pred = col(c).isNotNull() & (~isnan(c) if nan_as_null else lit(True))
    return sum(pred.cast("integer")).alias(c)

df.agg(*[count_not_null(c) for c in df.columns]).show()

## +---+---+---+---+
## |  v|  x|  y|  z|
## +---+---+---+---+
## |  2|  3|  4|  4|
## +---+---+---+---+
```

or if you want to treat `NaN` a `NULL`:

```
df.agg(*[count_not_null(c, True) for c in df.columns]).show()

## +---+---+---+---+
## |  v|  x|  y|  z|
## +---+---+---+---+
## |  1|  3|  4|  3|
## +---+---+---+---
```

You can also leverage SQL `NULL` semantics to achieve the same result without creating a custom function:

```
df.agg(*[
    count(c).alias(c)    # vertical (column-wise) operations in SQL ignore NULLs
    for c in df.columns
]).show()

## +---+---+---+
## |  x|  y|  z|
## +---+---+---+
## |  1|  2|  3|
## +---+---+---+
```

but this won't work with `NaNs`.

If you prefer fractions:

```
exprs = [(count_not_null(c) / count("*")).alias(c) for c in df.columns]
df.agg(*exprs).show()

## +------------------+------------------+---+
## |                 x|                 y|  z|
## +------------------+------------------+---+
## |0.3333333333333333|0.6666666666666666|1.0|
## +------------------+------------------+---+
```

or

```
# COUNT(*) is equivalent to COUNT(1) so NULLs won't be an issue
df.select(*[(count(c) / count("*")).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).show()

## +------------------+------------------+---+
## |                 x|                 y|  z|
## +------------------+------------------+---+
## |0.3333333333333333|0.6666666666666666|1.0|
## +------------------+------------------+---+
```

Scala equivalent:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, isnan, sum}

type JDouble = java.lang.Double

val df = Seq[(JDouble, JDouble, JDouble, JDouble)](
  (0.0, 1, 2, 3.0), (null, 3, 4, 5.0),
  (null, null, 6, 7.0), (java.lang.Double.NaN, 8, 9, java.lang.Double.NaN)
).toDF()


def count_not_null(c: Column, nanAsNull: Boolean = false) = {
  val pred = c.isNotNull and (if (nanAsNull) not(isnan(c)) else lit(true))
  sum(pred.cast("integer"))
}

df.select(df.columns map (c => count_not_null(col(c)).alias(c)): _*).show
// +---+---+---+---+                                                               
// | _1| _2| _3| _4|
// +---+---+---+---+
// |  2|  3|  4|  4|
// +---+---+---+---+

 df.select(df.columns map (c => count_not_null(col(c), true).alias(c)): _*).show
 // +---+---+---+---+
 // | _1| _2| _3| _4|
 // +---+---+---+---+
 // |  1|  3|  4|  3|
 // +---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: return sum(col(c).isNotNull().cast("integer")).alias(c) here does it automatically know which dataframe to access? Is it because we get the column names from that particular dataframe?

Comment: @Roshini Columns are meaningful only in a scope of specific SQL expression which defines bindings. In other word context of a given `select` defines how columns are resolved.

Comment: How to select the columns if the `nan` count is larger the a threshold number?

Comment: `TypeError: Column is not iterable` at first try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isNotNull()` :

```
df.where(df[YOUR_COLUMN].isNotNull()).select(YOUR_COLUMN).show()
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is pretty elegant and at least as pythonic as the above spark sql code (which is also excellent, but in many more simple contexts this code does just fine). Take an upvote. Upvotes for all!

Comment: Nulls and nans have different functions

Answer (score 0):

You may got `data type mismatch` Exception :

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'isnan(`date_hour`)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires (double or float) type, however, '`date_hour`' is of timestamp type.;
```

Better select numerical columns at first:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

def get_numerical_cols(df):
    return [i.name for i in df.schema  if str(i.dataType) in ('IntegerType', 'LongType', 'FloatType', 'DoubleType') ]

numcols = get_numerical_cols(df)
df_nan_rate = df.select([(count(when(isnan(c) | col(c).isNull(), c))/count(lit(1))).alias(c) for c in numcols])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

z = df.count()
(df.replace(float('nan'), None)
 .agg(*[F.expr(f'count({col})/{z} as {col}') for col in df.columns])
).show()
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

For *string and numeric* columns, `summary` is convenient.

- Count non-nulls:

  ```py
  df.summary("count").show()
  ```
- Count non-NaN:

  ```py
  df.replace(float("nan"), None).summary("count").show()
  ```

**Note.** `summary` would not return columns of other than string or numeric type (e.g. *date* type columns would be omitted from the result).

---

Full test:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(0.0, 1, 2, float("Nan")),
     (None, 3, 4, 5.0),
     (None, None, 6, 7.0),
     (float("Nan"), 8, 9, 7.0)],
    ["v", "x", "y", "z"])
df.show()
# +----+----+---+---+
# |   v|   x|  y|  z|
# +----+----+---+---+
# | 0.0|   1|  2|NaN|
# |null|   3|  4|5.0|
# |null|null|  6|7.0|
# | NaN|   8|  9|7.0|
# +----+----+---+---+

df.summary("count").show()
# +-------+---+---+---+---+
# |summary|  v|  x|  y|  z|
# +-------+---+---+---+---+
# |  count|  2|  3|  4|  4|
# +-------+---+---+---+---+

df.replace(float("nan"), None).summary("count").show()
# +-------+---+---+---+---+
# |summary|  v|  x|  y|  z|
# +-------+---+---+---+---+
# |  count|  1|  3|  4|  3|
# +-------+---+---+---+---+
```