# Spark Scala Dataframe describe non numeric columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, data-analysis

Is there a function similar to `describe()` for non numeric columns?

I'd like to gather stats about the 'data completeness' of my table. E.G.

- total number of records
- total number of null values
- total number of special values (e.g. 0s, empty strings, etc...)
- total number of distinct values
- other stuff like this...

data.describe() produces interesting values (count, mean, stddev, min, max) for numeric columns only. Is there anything that works well with Strings or other types?

Comment: I have been looking for a similar thing in python pandas. I haven't found a method that explicitly does it; however, I have noticed that when my data frame is solely composed of columns with type `object` (not `int`, `float`, etc.) df.describe() displays `count`,`unique`, `top`, `freq` instead of `count`, `mean`, `std`, etc.

Comment: so I'd recommend you give following a try in whatever api you are using: `data["categorical_col1", "categorical_col2"].describe() `

Answer (score 1):

There isn't. The problem is that basics statistics on numerical data are cheap. On categorical data some of these may require multiple data scans and unbounded (linear in terms of the number of records) memory.

Some are very cheap. For example counting NULL or empty: [Count number of non-NaN entries in each column of Spark dataframe with Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33900726/6910411)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of getting string columns statistics described in question:

```
  def getStringColumnProfile(df: DataFrame, columnName: String): DataFrame = {
    df.select(columnName)
      .withColumn("isEmpty", when(col(columnName) === "", true).otherwise(null))
      .withColumn("isNull", when(col(columnName).isNull, true).otherwise(null))
      .withColumn("fieldLen", length(col(columnName)))
      .agg(
        max(col("fieldLen")).as("max_length"),
        countDistinct(columnName).as("unique"),
        count("isEmpty").as("is_empty"),
        count("isNull").as("is_null")
      )
      .withColumn("col_name", lit(columnName))
  }

    def profileStringColumns(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
      df.columns.filter(df.schema(_).dataType == StringType)
        .map(getStringColumnProfile(df, _))
        .reduce(_ union _)
        .toDF
        .select("col_name"
          , "unique"
          , "is_empty"
          , "is_null"
          , "max_length")
    }
```

and this is the same for numeric columns

```
  def getNumericColumnProfile(df: DataFrame, columnName: String): DataFrame = {
    df.select(columnName)
      .withColumn("isZero", when(col(columnName) === 0, true).otherwise(null))
      .withColumn("isNull", when(col(columnName).isNull, true).otherwise(null))
      .agg(
        max(col(columnName)).as("max"),
        count("isZero").as("is_zero"),
        count("isNull").as("is_null"),
        min(col(columnName)).as("min"),
        avg(col(columnName)).as("avg"),
        stddev(col(columnName)).as("std_dev")
      )
      .withColumn("col_name", lit(columnName))
  }

    def profileNumericColumns(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
      df.columns.filter(
        Set("DecimalType", "IntegerType", "LongType", "DoubleType", "FloatType", "ShortType")
          contains df.schema(_).dataType.toString
      )
        .map(getNumericColumnProfile(df, _))
        .reduce(_ union _)
        .toDF
        .select("col_name",
          "col_type",
          "is_null",
          "is_zero",
          "min",
          "max",
          "avg",
          "std_dev")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit of code to help solve the problem of profiling non-numeric data.  Please see:
https://github.com/jasonsatran/spark-meta/

To help with performance, we can sample the data or select only the columns that we want to explicitly profile.