# spark dataframe null value count

Tags: apache-spark, null, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark and i want to calculate the null rate of each columns,(i have 200 columns), my function is as follows:

```
def nullCount(dataFrame: DataFrame): Unit = {
val args = dataFrame.columns.length
val cols = dataFrame.columns
val d=dataFrame.count()
println("Follows are the null value rate of each columns")
for (i <- Range(0,args)) {
  var nullrate = dataFrame.rdd.filter(r => r(i) == (-900)).count.toDouble / d
  println(cols(i), nullrate)
}
```

}

But I find it's too slow , is there any more effective way to do this ?

Comment: i set the null value as the -900 to avoid infor loss in model training

Answer (score 2):

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33901312) by [zero323](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1560062/zero323):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, count, when}

df.select(df.columns.map(c => (count(c) / count("*")).alias(c)): _*)
```

with -900:

```
df.select(df.columns.map(
  c => (count(when(col(c) === -900, col(c))) / count("*")).alias(c)): _*)
```