# pyspark counting the numbers of NA in each column and group by context

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on databricks project and trying to count for each column how many nulls there are and group it by specific context (sub_area)

nulls can be in a form of :
None, NaN and NA.
i know there are functions such as isnan under

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, count, isnan,
```

how do i count the number of NA value in each column, or a given specific value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SparkSQL: apply aggregate functions to a list of column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33882894/sparksql-apply-aggregate-functions-to-a-list-of-column)

Comment: how do i count a specific value in each column?

Comment: [Count number of non-NaN entries in each column of Spark dataframe with Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33900726)

Comment: This is for non nulls.... i need a specific value