# Multiple PySpark operations fail on dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

The `feature_1_(double)` and `feature_2_(double)` columns in the below dataframe (`df2`) are created using a dictionary lookup in a `udf` function. Calling

```
feature_1 = udf(lambda row: func1(row), DoubleType())
feature_2 = udf(lambda row: func2(row), DoubleType())
df1 = df.withColumn("feature_1_(double)", feature_1("domain_ids"))
df2 = df1.withColumn("feature_2_(double)", feature_2("domain_ids")).drop("domain_ids")
df2.show(5,False)
```

returns the following dataframe

```
+----------+-------+------------------+------------------+----+
|session_id|serp_id|feature_1_(double)|feature_2_(double)|url1|
+----------+-------+------------------+------------------+----+
|         0|      0|               2.0|               0.0|   0|
|         3|      1|               1.0|               0.0|   0|
|         4|      0|               5.0|               0.0|   0|
|         5|      2|               2.0|               0.0|   2|
|         5|      0|               3.0|               0.0|   1|
+----------+-------+------------------+------------------+----+
```

Which adheres to the following schema:

```
root
 |-- session_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- serp_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- feature_1_(double): double (nullable = false)
 |-- feature_2_(double): double (nullable = false)
 |-- url1: integer (nullable = true)
```

In order to use a multi class classifier to estimate class probabilities for `url1`, I want to assemble feature 1 and 2 as a vector by using `VectorAssembler`. However, performing

```
assembler = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols = ["feature_1_(double)", "feature_2_(double)"],
    outputCol = "features")

df3 = assembler.transform(df2)
df3.show(5)
```

returns the following error. Checking whether columns in `df3` contain null values according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33901312/5306359) approach yield the same error.

Any help is appreciated.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2456.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 89 in stage 533.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 89.3 in stage 533.0 (TID 49754, st446-w-0.europe-west2-b.c.sincere-hearth-236110.internal, executor 23): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 253, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 248, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 331, in dump_stream
    self.serializer.dump_stream(self._batched(iterator), stream)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 140, in dump_stream
    for obj in iterator:
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 320, in _batched
    for item in iterator:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 76, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: f(*a)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 55, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-102-205c8e3fad14>", line 2, in <lambda>
  File "<ipython-input-101-533a3b67fe1f>", line 45, in relevance
KeyError: 567

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:332)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage112.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:619)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:211)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage113.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:619)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1126)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1132)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1992)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:172)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1661)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1649)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1648)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1648)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1882)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1820)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2034)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2055)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3278)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2489)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2489)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3259)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2489)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2703)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:254)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor108.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 253, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 248, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 331, in dump_stream
    self.serializer.dump_stream(self._batched(iterator), stream)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 140, in dump_stream
    for obj in iterator:
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 320, in _batched
    for item in iterator:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 76, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: f(*a)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 55, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-102-205c8e3fad14>", line 2, in <lambda>
  File "<ipython-input-101-533a3b67fe1f>", line 45, in relevance
KeyError: 567

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:332)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage112.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:619)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:211)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage113.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:619)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1126)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1132)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1992)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:172)
```

Comment: It is possible that the error is caused by another part of the code which you didn't share here. The exception is `KeyError: 567`. Do you have any transformations which do a dictionary lookup?

Comment: Have you tried aliasing the column names so that they do not contain parentheses? There might be an issue with the DAG if it can't read the column names correctly.

Comment: @pault: yes that is correct. I use a dictionary lookup in a udf lambda function to create dataframe ```df```, which runs without errors. So, once having created dataframe ```df```, I am wondering why the assemble vector operation gives a ```KeyError``` since I am not calling any dictionary look up directly or indirectly.

Comment: *which runs without errors* - probably not because spark has lazy execution and doesn't execute your `udf` until an action is called. For a more detailed answer, please include a [mcve] with the `udf` step included.

Comment: The preview of the above showed dataframe ```df``` is collected through

```features = udf(lambda row: function(row), DoubleType())

df = df_D.withColumn("feature_1_(double)", features("domain_ids"))

df.show(5,False)``` where ```function``` contains a dictionary lookup. Since, this works without error can I assume the ```udf``` function works correctly? I will add this to the original question post.

Comment: No you can not assume that because the `udf` is not evaluated on the entire dataframe, just the 5 rows that are required for `show` to return a value. In general, you need to make your `udf`s robust to bad inputs.

Comment: Allright, thanks. Now, I know where to start debugging.