# How do I calculate the percentage of None or NaN values in Pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, data-cleaning, data-processing

I have a larger data-set in PySpark and want to calculate the percentage of None/NaN values per column and store it in another dataframe called percentage_missing. For example if the following were the input dataframe:

```
df = sc.parallelize([
    (0.4, 0.3),
    (None, None),
    (9.7, None), 
    (None, None)
]).toDF(["A", "B"])
```

I would like the output to be a dataframe where column 'A' contains the value 0.5 and column 'B' contains the value 0.75.

I am looking for something like this:

```
for column_ in my_columns:
  amount_missing = df[df[column_] == None].count().div(len(df)) * 100
```

If there is a library with a function that does this I would also be happy to use it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count number of non-NaN entries in each column of Spark dataframe with Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33900726/count-number-of-non-nan-entries-in-each-column-of-spark-dataframe-with-pyspark)

Comment: No, actually I asked the other way around. Count number of NaN entries. Not non-NaN entries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following code do exacly what you asked:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df:

+----+----+
|   A|   B|
+----+----+
| 0.4| 0.3|
|null|null|
| 9.7|null|
|null|null|
+----+----+

# Generic solution for all columns
amount_missing_df = df.select([(count(when(isnan(c) | col(c).isNull(), c))/count(lit(1))).alias(c) for c in df.columns])
amount_missing_df.show()

amount_missing_df:

+---+----+
|  A|   B|
+---+----+
|0.5|0.75|
+---+----+
```